# Struct memory allocation issues for message buffer

Tags: c, memory, struct

I'm trying to use static structs as a buffer for incoming messages, in order to avoid checking the buffer on the MCP2515-external unit. An ISR enters the function with a can_message* value 255 to actually read new messages from my MCP2515. 
Other applications register an ID in the message passed as argument, in order to check if the buffer holds any messages with the same value.
This returns wrong IDs, and the rest of the datafields are 0 and uninitialized. What is wrong?

can_message struct:

```c
typedef struct 
{
    uint8_t id;
    uint8_t datalength;
    uint8_t data[8];
}can_message;
```

```c
int CAN_message_receive(can_message* message)
{

    static volatile can_message* buffers = (volatile can_message*)0x18FF;
    static int birth = 1;
    if(birth)
    {
        for (int i; i < CAN_MESSAGE_UNIQUE_IDS; i++)
        {
                        //These structs gets addresses outside SRAM
            buffers[i] = (can_message){0,0,0};
        }
        birth = 0;
    }

    if (message == CAN_UPDATE_MESSAGES)
    {
        /* Sorts messages <3 */
        can_message currentMessage;
                //These functions are working:
        CAN_message_get_from_MCP_buf(&currentMessage, 0);
        buffers[currentMessage.id] = currentMessage;
        CAN_message_get_from_MCP_buf(&currentMessage, 1);
        buffers[currentMessage.id] = currentMessage;


        return 0;   //returns nothing !
    }
    if(buffers[message->id].id != 0)
    {
        printf("test\n");
                //This copy gives wrong id and data:
        memcpy(message, &buffers[message->id], sizeof(can_message));
        buffers[message->id].id = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Edit 1:
I did however notice that any buffers[i]-struct gets a totally different address than expected. It does not use the addresses following 0x18FF on the SRAM. Is there any way to change this?

Edit 2:
This is my main-loop:

```c
while (1) {

//printf("tx buf ready: %d\n", MCP2515_TX_buf_empty(0));
//CAN_Loopback_test();

_delay_ms(500);
        value = USART_ReadByte(0);
        CAN_message_receive(&msg);
        printf("CAN_receive: ID: %d, datalength: %d, data: \n",msg.id);
        for (int k; k < msg.datalength; k++)
        {
            printf("%d, ",msg.data[k]);
        }
        printf("\n");

    }
```

Edit 3: Changing the buffer-pointer to array solved the issue. (It does no longer use the SRAM, but whatever floats my boat)

```c
int CAN_message_receive(can_message* message)
{

    static can_message buffers[CAN_MESSAGE_UNIQUE_IDS];
    static int birth = 1;
    if(birth)
    {
        for (int i; i < CAN_MESSAGE_UNIQUE_IDS*10; i++)
        {
            *(char*)(0x18FF+i) = 0;
            printf("buffers: %X\n", &buffers[i]);
        }
        birth = 0;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is there on the address `0x18FF`? Some custom RAM? Why start at such a strange address? Where is the actual SPI data buffer? Also note that the line `static volatile can_message* buffers = 0x18FF;` is not even valid C, so your compiler is misconfigured.

Comment: Address 0x18FF is part of an external configured with ATmega162's external memory interface. The 'CAN_message_get_from_MCP_buf(can_message, buffer)-function is currently working as it should. All lower-level operations have been tested

Comment: I did however notice that any buffers[i]-struct gets a totally different address than expected. It does not use the addresses following 0x18FF on the SRAM. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: @JonasHjulstad Instead adding information in comments, [edit] your question and write everything there. Please add comments in your code to mark the locations you refer to in your problem description, e.g. where the wrong ID is returned or where you find the wrong addresses. How do you see that the address is wrong? In a debugger? What address do you see?

Comment: I wouldn't rule out anything, including the external memory not working as it should. You can however start by making the code valid C `static volatile can_message* buffers = (volatile can_message*)0x18FF;`. Also the `buffers[message->id]` part seems fishy. Do you allocate one buffer per CAN identifier? What if the identifier is invalid?

Comment: Oh, also... are you using a standard C setup or a minimum setup? That is, do you know if `static` variables are initialized correctly to begin with?

Comment: There is one buffer per CAN identifier, which is supposed to be adjustable if any new identifiers should be added to the bus. Recasting 0x18FF did not solve the issue.

Comment: The C setup is standard, I'm not very good either memory allocation or static initialization, which probably is the reason to this issue

Comment: please show more of your program. at least the parts that call `CAN_message_receive` and their logical place in the program flow.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Pointer to buffers changed to buffer-array:

```c
int CAN_message_receive(can_message* message)
{

    static can_message buffers[CAN_MESSAGE_UNIQUE_IDS];
    static int birth = 1;
    if(birth)
    {
        for (int i; i < CAN_MESSAGE_UNIQUE_IDS*10; i++)
        {
            *(char*)(0x18FF+i) = 0;
            printf("buffers: %X\n", &buffers[i]);
        }
        birth = 0;
    }
```

Comment: `&buffers[i]` overflows when `i >= CAN_MESSAGE_UNIQUE_IDS` (luckily you are not dereferencing it). And `&buffers[i]` is not the address of `(char*)(0x18FF+i)`, the latter is accessing individual bytes. Are you sure that you don't have some sort of a library header for accessing this? Using hardcoded addresses like this is a disaster waiting to happen. Also, `sizeof(can_message)` isn't guaranteed to be `10` (it most likely is but you shouldn't guess. Also, certain `memcpy` implementations cast the pointers to `int*` in order to copy larger chunks when both addresses are aligned.

Comment: What do you mean "solved"? Weren't you supposed to use an external memory? This code uses internal `.bss`, not external memory.

Comment: I went a bit back and forth with the printf-statement in order to see which addresses each individual struct ended up at, but I have no intention of leaving permanent in the code. I would (ideally) want to end up with the buffer stored in SRAM, but any solution works for now. Thanks for your replies, it was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest to decouple the ISR logic with the programs own message cache logic. Also the initializing logic with the `birth` variable looks unnecessary.

I would setup some ring buffer that the ISR can write messages to and from that the main code reads the data into the ID-lookup-buffer.

This would ensure that message updates does not interfere with readouts (at least if you check the read/write indices to your ring buffer) and also eliminates the need to put Mutexes around your whole message buffer.

Currently it smells very badly because of missing read/write synchronization.

```
// global
#define CAN_MESSAGE_UNIQUE_IDS 50
static can_message g_can_messagebuffers[CAN_MESSAGE_UNIQUE_IDS];

#define MAX_RECEIVEBUFFER 8
static volatile can_message g_can_ringbuffer[MAX_RECEIVEBUFFER];
static volatile int g_can_ringbufferRead  = 0;
static volatile int g_can_ringbufferWrite = 0;


// called from ISR
void GetNewMessages()
{
    // todo: check ring buffer overflow
    can_message currentMessage;
    CAN_message_get_from_MCP_buf(&g_can_ringbuffer[g_can_ringbufferWrite], 0);
    g_can_ringbufferWrite = (g_can_ringbufferWrite + 1) % MAX_RECEIVEBUFFER;

    CAN_message_get_from_MCP_buf(&g_can_ringbuffer[g_can_ringbufferWrite], 1);
    g_can_ringbufferWrite = (g_can_ringbufferWrite + 1) % MAX_RECEIVEBUFFER;
}


// called from main loop
void handleNewMessages()
{
  while(g_can_ringbufferRead  != g_can_ringbufferWrite){
    const can_message* currentMessage = &g_can_ringbuffer[g_can_ringbufferRead];
    if(currentMessage->id < CAN_MESSAGE_UNIQUE_IDS)
    {
      g_can_messagebuffers[currentMessage->id] = *currentMessage;
    }        
    g_can_ringbufferRead  = (g_can_ringbufferRead  + 1) % MAX_RECEIVEBUFFER;
  }
}

// called from whoever wants to know
// todo: 
//    really required a by value interface?
//    would it not be sufficient to return a pointer and
//    provide an additional interface to mark the message as used?
int getMsg(can_message* message)
{
  if(buffers[message->id].id != 0)
  {
    printf("test\n");
    *message =  &g_can_messagebuffers[message->id];
    g_can_messagebuffers[message->id].id = 0;
    return 0;
  }
  return -1;
}

// alternative to above 
const can_message* getMsg(int id)
{
  if(    (id < CAN_MESSAGE_UNIQUE_IDS)
      && (g_can_messagebuffers[id] != 0))
  {
    return &g_can_messagebuffers[id].id;
  }
  return NULL;
}

void invalidateMsg(int id)
{
  if(id < CAN_MESSAGE_UNIQUE_IDS)
  {
     g_can_messagebuffers[id] = 0;
  }
}
```

edit:
after your changes to an message array instead some strange pointer, there is also no need for the setup routine for this code.

edit:
if your micro controller already has a buffer for received messages, then may be it is unnecessary at all to register a ISR and you could empty it from the mainloop directly into your own id-lookup buffer (assuming the mainloop is fast enough)

Comment: Setting the buffer as library-static instead of static inside a function seems nice, and I didn't even think of the read/write-protection. I will try this as soon as i can, thanks!